# SetFilePointer on C# suddenly stop work

Tags: c#, pinvoke

Background:
In my project I need to scan my HDD sector by sector. I am using Pinvoke of Kernel32.dll. 
The size of the HDD is 160GB (nearly 312,000,000 LBA). 
The loop scans every single iteration 8000 sectors.

The problem:
Somehow, after scanning 40000 sectors successfuly, the loop stacks without moving, and I even cannot terminate the application unless I will disconnect the HDD (is external media). 
I know that my media doesn't have any corrupted sectors.

When setting the file pointer using SetFilePointer of Kernel32.dll, I pay attention to Low and High ints for offset, but the offset even not reaching 1GB, so I guess that there is nothing to do in this point, but somewhere else (I think so, but I am not sure, I am quite new to this Pinvoke).

This is my following code:

```
    public enum EMoveMethod : uint
    {
        Begin = 0,
        Current = 1,
        End = 2
    }

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern int SetFilePointer(
        [In] SafeFileHandle hFile,
        [In] int lDistanceToMove,
        [In, Out] ref int lpDistanceToMoveHigh,
        [In] EMoveMethod dwMoveMethod);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(string lpFileName, uint dwDesiredAccess,
      uint dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, uint dwCreationDisposition,
      uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal extern static int ReadFile(SafeFileHandle handle, byte[] bytes,
       int numBytesToRead, out int numBytesRead, IntPtr overlapped_MustBeZero);

    static public int BytesPerSector(int drive)
    {
        int driveCounter = 0;
        try
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");
            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
                if (driveCounter == drive)
                {
                    var t = queryObj["BytesPerSector"];
                    return int.Parse(t.ToString());
                }
                driveCounter++;
            }
        }
        catch (ManagementException) { return -1; }
        return 0;
    }

    static public int GetTotalSectors(int drive)
    {
        int driveCount = 0;
        try
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");
            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
                if (driveCount == drive)
                {
                    var t = queryObj["TotalSectors"];
                    return int.Parse(t.ToString());
                }
                driveCount++;
            }
        }
        catch (ManagementException) { return -1; }
        return -1;
    }

    static private byte[] DumpSector(string drive, int sector, int bytesPerSector)
    {
        const uint GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;
        const uint OPEN_EXISTING = 3;

        byte[] buf = null;
        try
        {
            SafeFileHandle handleValue = CreateFile(drive, GENERIC_READ, 0, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            if (handleValue.IsInvalid) { Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error()); }
            long sec = (long)sector * (long)bytesPerSector;
            buf = new byte[bytesPerSector];
            int read = 0, moveToHigh = (int)(sec >> 32);
            int Res=SetFilePointer(handleValue, (int)(sec & 0xffffffff), ref moveToHigh, EMoveMethod.Begin);
            if (Res == -1) { Console.WriteLine("ERROR: ");  return null; }
            if (ReadFile(handleValue, buf, bytesPerSector, out read, IntPtr.Zero)==0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: "); return null; 
            }
            handleValue.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception Ex) { Console.WriteLine("ERROR: {0}", Ex.Message); return null; }
        return buf;
    }

    static void Scanner()
    {
        if (DRV == -1) { Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Please select drive using <A>+ drive index number."); return; } // error
        const int BFB = 8000;
        byte[] b = DumpSector(HDDs[DRV], MyOffset, BlockSize * BFB);
        int Sec16 = 0, IntOff = 0, JMP = 0;
        string DMP = "";
        long FF = ((long)MyOffset * BlockSize) + (IntOff * 16);
        Console.Write("0x{0}   ", FF.ToString("X10"));
        for (int byt = 0; byt < b.Length; byt++)
        {
            DMP += (char)b[byt];
            Console.Write("{0} ", b[byt].ToString("X2"));
            Sec16++; FF++;
            if (Sec16 == 8) Console.Write("  ");
            if (Sec16 == 16)
            {
                Console.Write("  {0}", DMP.Replace("\x07", "").Replace("\x08", "").Replace("\x0a", "").Replace("\x0d", "").Replace("\x09", "")); Console.WriteLine();
                DMP = ""; Sec16 = 0; IntOff++; JMP++;
                if (JMP == 32) { JMP = 0; IntOff += 224; FF += 3584; byt += 3584; }
                Console.Write("0x{0}   ", FF.ToString("X10"));
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("- End of scan -");
    }
```

The program is Console application in order to speedup the process.

Comment: Try to encapsulate your code with try..catch so you can catch the error message.

Comment: I changed the code in DumpSector, but there is no exception.... It just simply stoped work...

Comment: It is very difficult to determine the cause if we don't know where to start.  but may be you are accessing some protected area such as paging memory used by the OS or operating system file. try not to read those area when you are in windows.

Comment: Pointless trying to help until you add error checking. Read the documentation for each and every API function, and add error checking. Concentrate on the Return Value section of the doc topics where error handling is described. SetFilePointerEx is easier to use that SetFilePointer. You also make life hard for us by posting wall of code. Don't do that. Strip this down to 30 line SSCCE.

Comment: Strange, I trying to read every random sector above this 40000 and it get stack....

Comment: And you ought to take care with your pinvoke declarations. You've copied each one from somewhere else and they each have different style. Is it kernel32 or kernel32.dll. CharSet.Auto or CharSet.Unicode? Use In/Out attributes or not? Concentrate harder on the details. Add error checking. And make a good SSCCE. See the wood from the trees.

Comment: Ok, after I changed my code and tested for many times, I succeed to reach up to sector 390400, but it stacks there and on every sector above it. The function DumpSector is stack in the command ReadFile and no error is thrown. I guess that if it is media error, it suppose to pop-up an error, right？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you had misused some API your program would not just have stopped. THis is unlikely to be an API usage error.

This is probably a hardware error. Non-killable processes are a typical symptom. A process can only be killed by Windows when the last pending IO is completed. The disk driver is waiting to complete your IO but the disk never responds (or only after a long timeout).

Comment: There is possibility to set timeout for hardware RAW reading in C#?

Comment: I don't know of any such thing in Windows. (This is not a C# issue.) Try it on a different disk (it will work). Replace the disk.

Comment: Because the disk just never responds. The firmware is incapable of dealing gracefully with the situation. No response => no error.